# Конфигурация nginx для Vue.js

Tags: apache, nginx, vue.js

Помогите, пожалуйста, сконфигурировать nginx для Vue.js. Так то работает, но если не в корневой директории, а скажем в www.mysite.com/books обновит страницу, то появляется ошибка "Not Found The requested URL /books/ was not found on this server." на сайте vue.js сказано, что нужно добавить в location try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;  [Server Configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) Я так сделал, а не работает все равно. Вот полная конфигурация nginx

```
server {
listen      ip:80;
server_name mySite;
error_log  /var/log/apache2/domains/mySite.error.log error;

location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|)$ {
    root /home/projects/files/images;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass     ip:8080;
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
        root           /home/admin/web/mySite/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/mySite.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/mySite.bytes bytes;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/mySite.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/mySite/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      ip:8080;
}

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

include /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.mySite.conf*;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, тк у меня связка из Nginx + Apache, то в корень проекта нужно еще добавить .htaccess со следующим содержимым

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

И все заработает

Comment: зачем тут апач не понятно)